# how to check number odd even python?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I show even and odd in `print (x ,"is" )`?

```
num_list = list(range(1, 51))
odd_nums = []
even_nums = []

for x in num_list:    
    if x % 2 == 0:        
        even_nums.append(x)
    else:       
        odd_nums.append(x)
    print (x ,"is" )
```

Comment: You are already checking if the value is odd or even, just add a print statement within the if-else block to print out that it's odd or even. Would you please specify what specifically is tripping you up?

Answer (score 1):

Sol 1 - Using list comprehension -

```
print([("even" if x%2 == 0 else "odd") for x in range(10)])
```

Sol 2 - Using list comprehension -

```
print([x for x in range(10) if x%2 ==0])
```

Sol 3 -
Using dictionary comprehension -

```
di = {x:("even" if x%2 == 0 else "odd") for x in range(10)}
print(di)
```

Sol 4 - Using filter() -

```
li = list(range(20))
print(list(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0,li)))
print(list(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 1,li)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Already checking it, if you wanna display "Odd" or Even" you can simply put a print statement within if-else statement;

```
num_list = list(range(1, 51))
odd_nums = []
even_nums = []

for x in num_list:    
    if x % 2 == 0:        
        even_nums.append(x)
        print (x ,"is a even number")
    else:       
        odd_nums.append(x)
        print (x ,"is a odd number")
```

Answer (score 0):

As easy as adding this:

```
num_list = list(range(1, 51))
odd_nums = []
even_nums = []

for x in num_list:    
    if x % 2 == 0:        
        even_nums.append(x)
        print (x ,"is even" )
    else:       
        odd_nums.append(x)
    print (x ,"is odd" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code already works properly all you could do is update your print statement like this.

```
num_list = list(range(1, 51))
odd_nums = []
even_nums = []

for x in num_list:    
    if x % 2 == 0:        
        even_nums.append(x)
        print (x ,"is even" )
    else:       
        odd_nums.append(x)
        print (x ,"is odd" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcut if at the end of code

```
num_list = list(range(1, 51))
odd_nums = []
even_nums = []

for x in num_list:
    is_odd = x % 2
    if  is_odd:        
        odd_nums.append(x)
    else:       
        even_nums.append(x)
    print (x ,"is",  "odd" if is_odd else "even" )
```